# Django-page-cms deployment insert error

Tags: django, deployment, django-cms, integrity

and thanks for taking the time to read my question.

I am using django 1.3 with postgresql. I have django-page-cms 1.4.5 installed. I added pages to my installed apps, run manage.py syncdb, and manage.py migrate. On my remote dev server, I can navigate the to admin/pages, and get to the add page form. However, when I try to do the insert (submit the form) I get the following error:

```
IntegrityError: insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint 
"django_admin_log_content_type_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id)=(24) is not present in table "django_content_type".
```

When I do a select on my django_content_type table, there are three rows for pages:

```
 20 | content              | pages             | content
 21 | pagepermission       | pages             | pagepermission
 22 | pagealias            | pages             | pagealias
```

I am able to insert pages on my local dev server. And the id for pagealias in my local db django_content_type is 24.

How did this carry over from local to remote? Shouldn't this be taken from the relevant db? How can I fix this?

Remote: ubuntu, Local: win7

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had actually the same problem with two instances of the database on the remote server. Both were cached by the same instance of memcache and this was the problem.

I could fix it by creating separated instances of memcache, restarting the servers and doing a syncdb.

Comment: Thank you. I had gotten around this, but this seems to be a correct answer.